# Is the problem of traversing every vertex of a graph (not necessarily once) without crossing an edge more than once in P?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard

I know that finding a Hamiltonian circuit is in NP and I know that finding an Eulerian circuit is in P. However, what about the following problem:

- Must leave the starting vertex and visit every other vertex;
- You may only return to the start after visiting every other vertex;
- You can visit the same vertex multiple times, as long as it's not the starting vertex;
- You don't have to use every edge in the graph, but each edge can only be used once.

Is that in P or NP-hard? I tried different approaches to this but now I don't know if I'm wasting my time in case this problem doesn't have an efficient solution.

Comment: Without loss of generality the path never returns to the start vertex (otherwise truncate the path just before it first returns to the starting vertex, and the result still meets all your conditions), so you're asking if there is a path that starts at the starting vertex, never returns to the starting vertex, visits every vertex at least once, and traverses each edge at most once.  It's certainly in NP.

Comment: If the starting vertex doesn't have at least two edges, the answer is false. Otherwise isn't this equivalent to whether deleting zero or more edges admits an Eulerian cycle? Also, nitpicking but NP includes P so the question is whether it is in P or NP $\setminus$ P.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, I don't think it's equivalent to checking for a Eulerian cycle, because the Eulerian cycle might violate the 2nd requirement (it might return to the starting vertex before visiting every other vertex).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret How to determine whether deleting zero or more edges admits an Eulerian cycle?

Comment: @D.W. Let $S$ be the set of neighbors of the starting vertex, then remove the starting vertex. The problem becomes whether there is an Eulerian path (after deleting some edges) from one vertex in $S$ to another vertex in $S$.

Comment: @xskxzr I can't think of a way, and I have the feeling that it's NP-hard or at least not in P. It's equivalent to pairing up vertices with odd degree and choosing edge-disjoint paths between them such that if all edges on those paths are deleted, the graph is still connected; the resulting vertices will all have even degree and there will be an Eulerian cycle.

Comment: @D.W. To force not returning to the start early, the starting vertex would need exactly two edges. But there are polynomially many pairs of edges out of a set of at least two. So enumerate all pairs and check if any pair admits a Eulerian cycle, deleting some additional edges. However, the deleting edges aspect seems like a constraint problem that some NP complete problem could be reduced to.

Comment: For directed graph, [it is NP-hard](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/psets/ps3-solutions.pdf).

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret It is indeed equivalent to deciding whether deleting zero or more edges admits an Eulerian cycle.

Comment: ... OK, it doesn't work in both directions. For the "in NP" direction: expand each vertex into a clique, then Hamilonian cycles in the new graph can be mapped to walks in the original graph.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to expand vertices in a way that allows reduction from the Hamiltonian cycle problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard.

Consider the following variants:

**Variant 1:** given a graph where each vertex has degree at most three, determine if there is a Hamiltonian path.

**Variant 2:** given a graph, determine if there is a trail (a path without repeated edges) that visits every vertex at least once.

Variant 1 is NP-hard [1].

Variant 1 can be reduced to variant 2 by mapping to the same graph.

If there is a Hamiltonian path on the graph, the Hamiltonian path is certainly a trail that visits every vertex at least once.

On the other hand, if there is a trail from $u$ to $v$ that visits every vertex at least once, since every vertex in the graph has degree at most three, every vertex except $u$ and $v$ must appear exactly once on the trail. If every vertex appears exactly once, the trail itself is a Hamiltonian path. If $u$ and/or $v$ appear twice, remove the first and/or the last edges on the trail respectively, then the trail becomes a Hamiltonian path. Anyway there is a Hamiltonian path in the graph.

So variant 2 is NP-hard.

---

Suppose the problem in OP is in P. Given an instance of variant 2, construct a new graph for every pair of vertexes $(u,v)$ by adding a new vertex $s$ and new edges $(s,u)$ and $(v,s)$. Now there is a trail that visits every vertex at least once in the original graph if and only if the answer to the problem in OP on at least one of these new graphs is "yes". So one can solve variant 2 in polynomial time by solving the problem in OP on these new graphs. So the problem in OP is NP-hard.

---

<sub>[1] Garey, M. R.; Johnson, D. S.; Stockmeyer, L. (1974), "Some simplified NP-complete problems", *Proc. 6th ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC '74),* pp. 47–63, [doi:10.1145/800119.803884](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=800119.803884).</sub>